# Problem reading file,searching, and displaying information to an array of structures in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Sorry if this seems dumb, I am pretty new to C++ and I'm having trouble displaying information read into an array of structures from an input file.

I have 3 functions. One for reading my file into the array, one for prompting the user to search for a specific struct in the array, and the last one for displaying the contents of the array.

I don't know for certain if my `readFile()` or `displayAllStudents()` is broken. I am able to output the first line from the file, but the rest is 0. Next my `selectStudent()` is probably terrible; I'm having trouble finding a good solution for what I'm trying to accomplish.

I've tried many solutions posted here, but my issue seems unique so I'm hoping I can help pointed in the right direction.

```
Input file and desired output.


    ID   CLA   OLA   Quiz   Homework   Exam   Bonus   Total   FinalGrade   
c088801    10    15      4         15     56       5 
c088802     9    12      2         11     46       2 
c088803     8    10      3         12     50       1
c088804     5     5      3         10     53       3
c088805     3    11      1         10     45       0 
c088806     8    14      2         11     40      -1  
c088807     4    12      2         12     48      -2
c088808    10    10      3         11     36       0
c088809     8     8      3         11     39       0
c088810     6     9      4          9     47       3
c088811     8     7      3         13     41       3
c088812     4    11      3         11     37       1
c088813     9    15      2          8     50       2
c088814     8    12      2         10     48       4
c088815     6     8      1          7     45       1
c088816     7     7      2          6     51       2
c088817     8     9      2         12     38       2
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
    char ID[7];
    int CLA;
    int OLA;
    int Quiz;
    int Homework;
    int Exam;
    int Bonus;
    int Total;
    int FinalGrade;
};
const int SIZE = 20;

//Function prototypes
void readFile(Student[]);
int selectStudent(Student[]);
void displayAllStudents(Student[]);

int main() {
    Student Roster[SIZE] = {};                  //Initalizes array

    readFile(Roster);
    //selectStudent(Roster);
    displayAllStudents(Roster);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//This function will read the text file into our array of structures.
void readFile(Student Roster[]) {
    ifstream inFile("point.dat");                   //Reads input file
    string line;

    getline(inFile, line);                          //Skips first line of file

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {                
            inFile >> Roster[i].ID >> Roster[i].CLA >> Roster[i].OLA >>
                Roster[i].Quiz >> Roster[i].Homework >> Roster[i].Exam >>
                Roster[i].Bonus >> Roster[i].Total >> Roster[i].FinalGrade;
    }

}

//This function will prompt user to select an individual student ID
//then display that student's information.
int selectStudent(Student Roster[]) {
    char* cNumber;

    cout << "Please enter the student's c-number:" << endl;
    cin >> cNumber;

    for(int i; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(strcmp(Roster[i].ID, cNumber)==0){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

//This function will display all our student information
void displayAllStudents(Student Roster[]) {
    cout << "     ID   CLA   OLA   Quiz   Homework   Exam   Bonus   Total   FinalGrade" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << Roster[i].ID[0] << Roster[i].ID[1] << Roster[i].ID[2] << Roster[i].ID[3] << Roster[i].ID[4] << Roster[i].ID[5] << Roster[i].ID[6]
            << " " << Roster[i].CLA << " " << Roster[i].OLA << " " << Roster[i].Quiz << " " <<
            Roster[i].Homework << " " << Roster[i].Exam << " " << Roster[i].Bonus << " " <<
            Roster[i].Total << " " << Roster[i].FinalGrade << endl;
    }
}
```

```
My output.

     ID   CLA   OLA   Quiz   Homework   Exam   Bonus   Total   FinalGrade
c088801 10 15 4 15 56 5 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: one of your reads from `inFile` is probably failing, you need to check `inFile.good()` (or simply the boolean value of `inFile` instead) in each iteration of your for loop and stop and print an error. After a failed read all subsequent reads also fail until `clear()` is called.

Comment: your input only contains 6 numbers but you are attempting to read 8 which is why the read fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `readFile`, when you're reading the contents of your file here, you've assumed that all fields for every Student struct contain data.

```
        inFile >> Roster[i].ID >> Roster[i].CLA >> Roster[i].OLA >>
            Roster[i].Quiz >> Roster[i].Homework >> Roster[i].Exam >>
            Roster[i].Bonus >> Roster[i].Total >> Roster[i].FinalGrade;
```

Since your input doesn't have content in the `Total` and `FinalGrade` columns, when your program hits `>> Roster[i].Total` for the first time it's actually trying to read the second student's id, *c088802*, which isn't the integer value expected by `Roster[i].Total`.

If you know your input data will never have content in the `Total` and `FinalGrade` columns, you can remove `>> Roster[i].Total >> Roster[i].FinalGrade` from your file read loop.

If you know your input data might not be complete, but don't know how much of the row will be filled, something like this should work, though there's likely a better way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    getline(infile, line);
    stringstream ss(line);

    ss >> Roster[i].ID;

    int value, count = 0;
    while(ss >> value){
        switch(count)
        {
           case 0: Roster[i].CLA = value;
           break;
           case 1: Roster[i].OLA = value;
           break;
           case 2: Roster[i].Quiz = value;
           break;
           ...
           case 7: Roster[i].FinalGrade = value;
           break;
        }
        ++count;
    }        
}
```

Comment: This was it! I can finally give my head a break from repeatedly slamming against my keyboard. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! @OhJustin you can consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark to indicate to the wider community that you've found a solution. Accepting an answer also gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself, and there's no obligation to do this. Take a look at some of the other answers as well, some of them offer better ways to approach the problems you presented with techniques you'll likely come across as you keep learning C++.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should change your perspective and have the object read its members from the stream:

```
struct Student
{
    std::string ID;
    //...
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Student& s);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Student& s)
{
    input >> s.ID;
    input >> s.CLA;
    //...
    input >> s.FinalGrade;
    return input;
};
```

You can then read in the data with a simple loop:

```
std::vector<Student> database;
Student s;
while (infile >> s)
{
    database.push_back(s);
}
```

I've made two subtle changes here:  1) Use of `std::string` for the ID and 2) Using `std::vector` instead of an array.

The `std::vector` is an excellent data structure to use when reading from files, as it expands as necessary.  With an array, you will have to keep checking for overflow and reallocating as necessary to accommodate new items.

I believe your issue is using `operator>>` with a character array.  There is no method to  limit the input to the size of your array.  You may want to increase your array by 1 to allow for the terminating nul character (which may be appended by `operator>>`).  The C-style strings (arrays of characters) are terminated by a nul character so you will always need that extra array slot.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with the statements from Thomas Matthews.

Additionally I would like to show a full example.

I packed all the student **data** and **methods**  in one `struct Student`. All the integer data are stored in one `std::vector` and can be accessed via an index. This makes life easier.

Then we overload the extractor operator. With that, we can easily read the complete data for one student. For debug purposes, we overload also the inserter.

Please note: With that, reading of all student data into a vector is an one-liner, by simply using the vectors range constructor.

Also the output of all data is an ultra simple one-liner.

For the fun of it, I added also `the printSelectedStudendData` function.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::istringstream testDataFile(
R"#(c088801    10    15      4         15     56       5 
c088802     9    12      2         11     46       2 
c088803     8    10      3         12     50       1
c088804     5     5      3         10     53       3
c088805     3    11      1         10     45       0 
c088806     8    14      2         11     40      -1  
c088807     4    12      2         12     48      -2
c088808    10    10      3         11     36       0
c088809     8     8      3         11     39       0
c088810     6     9      4          9     47       3
c088811     8     7      3         13     41       3
c088812     4    11      3         11     37       1
c088813     9    15      2          8     50       2
c088814     8    12      2         10     48       4
c088815     6     8      1          7     45       1
c088816     7     7      2          6     51       2
c088817     8     9      2         12     38       2 
)#");

constexpr size_t NumberOfEntriesToRead = 6;

struct Student
{
    std::string ID;             // Student ID
    std::vector<int> data;      // Student related Data

    // Overload extractor operator >> to read all elements of a student
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Student& s) {
        s.data.clear(); is >> s.ID; 
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(is), NumberOfEntriesToRead, std::back_inserter(s.data));
        return is;
    }

    // Overload inserter operator << to write all elements of a student to a stream
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Student& s) {
        os << std::setw(10) << s.ID;    
        std::for_each(s.data.begin(), s.data.end(), [&os](int i) { os << std::setw(10) << i; });
        return os;
    }
};

void printSelectedStudendData(std::vector<Student>& vs)
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter the c-number of the student:\n\n";
    std::string cNumber{}; std::cin >> cNumber;
    std::vector<Student>::iterator found = std::find_if(vs.begin(), vs.end(), [&cNumber](const Student & s) {return s.ID == cNumber; });
    if (found != vs.end()) 
        std::cout << "\n\nData of student with c-Number '" << cNumber << "'  :\n\n" << *found << "\n\n\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "\n\nCould not find Student with c-Number '" << cNumber << "'\n\n\n";

}

int main()
{
    // Read all data in vector of students. Use vectors range constructor
    std::vector<Student> students{ std::istream_iterator<Student>(testDataFile), std::istream_iterator<Student>()};

    // Search for a student and show his data
    printSelectedStudendData(students);

    // Write all Data to console
    std::copy(students.begin(), students.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Student>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps . . .